# How to send data from an activity to another activity's specific fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to send some string data from an activity to another activity's specific fragment. In my case, I've an activity named MainAcitivity for sending data and reviving activity which has two fragments in viewpager named AddNew.class. The one fragment named AddExpense and second AddLedger. Now i want to receive data from AddExpense fragment only not from AddLedger fragment. How can i do that. 
I've send data by this code by a button click,

MainActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddNew.class);
                            intent.putExtra("edit_expense", "zohaib");
                            startActivity(intent);
```

Receiving activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Add Expense"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Add Ledger"));

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager2);
        final TabAdapter adapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener (new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
```

The fragment where from i want to revive data only but I've two fragments so not want to receive data from other. 
receiving Fragment:

```
 public class AddExpenseFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_expense, container, false);


AddNew activity = (AddNew) getActivity();
    Utility.shortToast(getActivity(), activity.getIntent().getExtras().getString("edit_expense"));
                return view;
            }
```

The problem in above code, when AddNew acitivty created the Toast shows either AddExpenseFragment selected or not but i don't want this. I want to receive data only from that fragment in which from i want to receive. Kindly resolve this problem.

Comment: You can do it with an interface.

Comment: use shared preferences !! no headache to control flow of fragments .

Comment: Best solution is to implement EVENT BUS. That gives you freedom of data passing between any fragment and activity

Comment: @Radhye good option

Comment: @Divyesh please give me a example of Event bus

Comment: Wait 10 mins,  i post code of event bus.

Comment: @Divyesh ok i'm waiting thanks

Comment: Create a Getter and Setter in fragment where you want to receive and after opening the fragment use setter to pass the data

Comment: If you want event base communication then try http://square.github.io/otto/ , if it is across app, else use simple observer design pattern of java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should override `setUserVisibleHint` method in your AddExpenseFragment and put your receiving intent code in it

Comment: i've override by this code but it crashed app. @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        AddNew activity = (AddNew) getActivity();
        Utility.shortToast(getActivity(), activity.getIntent().getExtras().getString("edit_expense"));
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    }

Comment: can you put the logcat here

Comment: 11-10 11:06:55.588 530-530/com.example.zohaibsiddique.expensecalculator D/fdgh: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent com.example.zohaibsiddique.expensecalculator.AddNew.getIntent()' on a null object reference

Comment: put your code in this if, it may solve the problem `if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {}`

Comment: you've best solution thanks bro. I've solved by sheardpreferences

Answer (score 0):

you can create a method in AddNew class that recieves the intent data and then call this method with the data from fragments

```
/* Method in AddNew Activity*/
    private void yourIntentData()
    { 
     return yourdata; 
    }

/* Method in AddExpenseFragment,type cast and call from the above parent class */
      ((AddExpenseFragment)getActivity).yourIntentData();
```

Answer (score 0):

compile This:

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Now, In your activity or fragment from where you send data to another fragment/activity:

```
private EventBus bus=EventBus.getDefault();
```

and use method to send desire value:

```
bus.post(new Message("EventBus data"));
```

Create Model class to pass complex data:

```
public class Message{
    private final String message;

       .....SET MORE VARIABLES AS PER YOUR NEED....

    public Message(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

In your data accepting activity:

```
EventBus bus=EventBus.getDefault();




.....THIS METHOD IS GETTING DATA......
 @Subscribe
    public void onLoginEvent(Message event){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),event.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        bus.register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        bus.unregister(this);
        super.onStop();
    }
```

If you have fragment then, just use

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        bus.register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        bus.unregister(this);
    }
```

Comment: you implement it? is it helped you?